# Swift: application:openURL: method not being called

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement the following framework in an empty project:

https://github.com/spotify/SpotifyLogin

This method should be called from AppDelegate but is not:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // This is not called
}
```

According to the documentation, this method is not called if your implementations return false from both the `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` methods.

However, this is not the case in my app, which explicitly returns true.

- I created a new project
- followed the steps to removing `SceneDelegate` from my project
- Added code from github link to Info.plist (pic below)
- copied and pasted the App Delegate from the above github link
- added my custom URL scheme in the Target's URL Types (pic below)

I tried googling, found this [question of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350623/applicationopenurl-method-not-being-called) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624786/method-applicationopenurloptions-is-not-called) - but neither helped

however, `application:openURL:options:` is not getting called

This is my ApplicationDelegate

```
import UIKit
import SpotifyLogin
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        print("DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
        let redirectURL: URL = URL(string: "myscheme://callback/")!
        SpotifyLogin.shared.configure(clientID: "###CLIENTID##",
                                      clientSecret: "###CLIENTSECRET##",
                                      redirectURL: redirectURL)
      
        print("Returning true")
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print("Delegate method called")
        let handled = SpotifyLogin.shared.applicationOpenURL(url) { data in
            print("Something happened in here")
            print(data)
        }
        return handled
    }
    
  
    
    

}
```

How I set up my URL Scheme

[image]

My `Info.plist`

[image]

Comment: That's because you are using SceneDelegate?

Comment: I'm not @ElTomato

Comment: In Xcode, go to your app's target and select the Info tab. At the bottom, of the screen you will find URL Types, expand the list and create a new one.

did you do this line . from here : https://github.com/spotify/SpotifyLogin

Comment: @RB's - yup. I added a picture to the OP

Comment: your url must be `snipitfm2://callback/` or `snipitfm2://`. check it must be same as spotify so try this `spotify://`

Comment: ^ Change my URL scheme or change the URL in app delegate?

Comment: you need to check both and it should be same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233215/discussion-between-rbs-and-marko-calvocruz).